# Can not run Android project in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android

I've created a test Xamarin.Forms project with all the defaults using the cross-platform. But when I run it I am getting this error and I don't know how to fix it. I re-installed Xamarin few times but still getting the same error. It won't even compile.

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: Error: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main  :  Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (Test)

Please help.

Comment: Have you Googled `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 `?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to the Java SE Development kit.
You need to download it and then it should work.

Look at the following post:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/62664/error-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-com-android-dx-command-main-createdatabasewithadonet